# Extending RTCPeerConnection with ES6 class

Tags: javascript, webrtc, ecmascript-6

I'm playing around with ES6 (es2015?) and WebRTC, and I would like to have a class that abstracts some of the behavior of the PeerConnection. I'm having the following issues with two different solutions:

**1. Using prefixed RTCPeerConnection**

```
class Connection extends webkitRTCPeerConnection {
    constructor() {
        super(null); //or some config
    }
    connect(endpoint) {
        //Do something with the PeerConnection
    }
}
var c = new Connection(); //Error here.
```

This causes the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

**2. Using webrtc-adapter.js**

```
import adapter from 'webrtc-adapter';
class Connection extends adapter.RTCPeerConnection {
    constructor() {
        super(null);
    }
    connect(endpoint) {
        //Error caused when calling this method.
    }
}

var c = new Connection(); //Works fine, can use PC methods etc.
c.connect(....); //Uncaught TypeError: c.connect is not a function
```

I transpile my program using babel with the 'es2015' preset and run it in Chrome 46, in case that makes any difference.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is it not legal to add new methods to subclasses? Or is there something related to my usage of PeerConnection?
Any help or alternative solutions would be appretiated.

Comment: At least the native `RTCPeerConnection` does not seem to be extensible. Also, you're probably transpiling this to ES5, where subclassing just doesn't work.

Comment: I recommend the official and actively managed https://github.com/webrtc/adapter instead. It gives you the modern standards-compliant RTCPeerConnection with es6-promise-based API (shimmed in Chrome, native in Firefox). Who knows, that might negate some of the reasons you're trying to subclass it, which I don't know if is possible atm.

Comment: @Frigo You can just extend the WebRtc object like so: https://jsfiddle.net/hg3pej4u/4/ here I am adding a method to give me back a custom property, but you can do whatever with it. Is this what you are looking for?